# How to retrieve dictionary that matches the value in another text file

Tags: python, dictionary, key, match, key-value

I have a text file with some values in it.
My text file:

```
297147
339761
357586
94922
207611
572399
575970
304557
218365
286313
29984
11511
323460
516916
21711
313386
402639
457584
488377
301753
183319
397063
497660
235784
319073
```

I have another .json file that contains dictionaries.
My json file:

```
{
   "license":4,
   "file_name":"COCO_val2014_000000522418.jpg",
   "coco_url":"http://images.cocodataset.org/val2014/COCO_val2014_000000522418.jpg",
   "height":480,
   "width":640,
   "date_captured":"2013-11-14 11:38:44",
   "flickr_url":"http://farm1.staticflickr.com/1/127244861_ab0c0381e7_z.jpg",
   "id":522418
},
{
   "license":3,
   "file_name":"COCO_val2014_000000184613.jpg",
   "coco_url":"http://images.cocodataset.org/val2014/COCO_val2014_000000184613.jpg",
   "height":336,
   "width":500,
   "date_captured":"2013-11-14 12:36:29",
   "flickr_url":"http://farm3.staticflickr.com/2169/2118578392_1193aa04a0_z.jpg",
   "id":184613
},
```

I want to retrive those dictionaries in **json** file whose "**id"s** match with the values in **text** file

I tried a code

```
#to retrive the json file key **"id"**
import json
    
with open("file.json") as f:
  data_retreived= json.load(f) 
a=data_retreived["images"]
for d in a:
     print(d['id']) 


#to retrieve the text_file values
q = open("/content/drive/MyDrive/coco/data.txt", "r")
li=q.readlines()
print(li)
```

Now I am trying something like this to retrieve the matching values

```
res=[]
for wt in li:
  for f in a:
    if wt == f['id']:
      res.append(f)
print(res)
```

But it gives me output:

> None

Comment: [**PLEASE DO NOT POST TEXT AS IMAGES**](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Copy and paste the text into your question and use the code formatting tool to format it correctly. Images are not searchable, and can not be interpreted by screen readers for those with visual impairments. Use the [edit] link to modify your question.

Comment: @MattDMo I just edited

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`json.load(f)` automatically parses integers into `int`s. While `q.readlines()` doesn't and reads them as strings. So `if wt == f['id']` compares a string with an integer which is always false. Try `if int(wt) == f['id']`.